# How to get user's DPI scale in win xp/10?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dpi

I tried:

```
QApplication::setAttribute (Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, true);
```

This works badly. It sets the scale to x1 if the user scale is <150% and x2, if the scale is> 150%.

```
QApp->devicePixelRatio();
```

Works similarly: returns 1 or 2.

I need:

```
If the custom user scale = 100%, then the scale of the interface is 100%  
If the custom user scale = 125%, then the scale of the interface is 125%  
If the custom user scale = 175%, then the scale of the interface is 175%
```

etc.

I tried:

```
Qputenv ("QT_SCALE_FACTOR", QByteArray ("1.75"));
```

And it worked great! That's what I need.
But for this, I need to know the custom scale before creating QApplication. How to get it?
The solution should work on all systems from win xp to win 10

App Manifest:

```
<asmv3:application>
  <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
    <dpiAware>True/PM</dpiAware>
  </asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>
```

Comment: You probably need to declare application as DPI-aware in manifest and then call `::GetDeviceCaps(::GetDC(NULL), LOGPIXELSX);`

Comment: [Writing DPI-Aware Desktop and Win32 Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266.aspx).

Comment: Seems like he is using Qt, which isn't native, so Qt probably has its own specific toggle for this. That said, one would still need to update their code to not use explicit pixel sizes. There seems to be lots of information on [Qt's documentation for HiDPI](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html).

Comment: @VTT ::GetDeviceCaps(::GetDC(NULL), LOGPIXELSX); allways return 96 (DPI-aware enabled).

Comment: @tambre  i already read this, it's not help to determ user's DPI scaling. QApp->devicePixelRatio(); return only 1 or 2, but i need 1.25, 1.5 etc.

Comment: upd. @VTT ::GetDeviceCaps(::GetDC(NULL), LOGPIXELSX); return alleays 120 after init QApplication. If i try use this before QApplication, the app crushing

Comment: Now this is strange, because these functions do not depend on QApplication anyhow.

Comment: @VTT my mistake, app crushed because i used qDebug() before init QApplication. But GetDeviceCaps still return 96 on any scales (125%, 175% etc)

Comment: You probably have not manifested your application binary to indicate that it is high-DPI aware. If you don't do that, the OS will lie to you about what the DPI settings actually are. This would explain why `LOGPIXELSX` is returning 96. This is a topic that I know quite a bit about for native Win32 (the normal way would be to call `GetDpiForMonitor`), but I'm not sure if Qt is doing its own thing here, instead of playing by the OS's normal rules, so I'll refrain from writing an answer. I don't have Qt installed anywhere for testing purposes.

Comment: @CodyGray may be i made mistake in manifest? Added my manifeste to topic. GetDpiForMonitor not supported on WinXP.